# Known limitations when inviting users to Dynamics 365 using Azure AD B2B

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm-online, azure-ad-b2b

We are designing a Dynamics 365 solution for a customer that already have an existing tenant with an Azure AD that uses federation through AD-FS.

We would like to design a solution using a separate tenant and Azure AD with Dynamics 365 (online). The idea would then be that we should invite users from their tenant to "our" tenant using Azure AD B2B.

We've found that there are limitations using Unified Service Desk client and using the users own email, using this approach. Are there other known limitations?

Could this be solved in a better way, still using two separate tenants?

Comment: Invited users will not be able to use the Unified Service Desk client to log into the host tenant’s Dynamics 365, and global admins and limited admins can use the Azure portal to invite B2B collaboration users to the directory. For the details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/invite-users-azure-active-directory-b2b-collaboration#incompatibilities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft states that the following features are not supported when using Azure B2B together with Dynamics 365:

- Unified Service Desk client
- Dynamics 365 App for Outlook
- Invited users cannot perform email activity using their own email address
- Office 365 Groups

Read details at [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/invite-users-azure-active-directory-b2b-collaboration#incompatibilities)